# Blazor onchange for datepicker not firing

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a small component that takes three date values and saves them. On the front end when the start date is chosen I want my preview date to change to two days before the start date. Here is what I have written.

My Class:

```
    public class AdDate
    {
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? PreviewDate { get; set; }
    }
```

My component:

```
           <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <strong>Day</strong>
                    </div>
                       <div class="col-md-3">
                        <strong>Preview Date</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <strong>Start Date</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <strong>End Date</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label>Thursday</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-md-3">
                        <RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value=@thursdayDate.PreviewDate DateFormat="d" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value=@thursdayDate.StartDate @onchange="@changePreviewDate" DateFormat="d" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value=@thursdayDate.EndDate TValue="DateTime?" DateFormat="d" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            

                }
            </div>
```

And my logic to have the date change:

```
    void changePreviewDate(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedStartDateString = e.Value.ToString();
        DateTime selectedStartDate = DateTime.Parse(selectedStartDateString);
        thursdayDate.PreviewDate = selectedStartDate.AddDays(-2);  

    }
```

My onchange even does not fire at all. I have also tried the following with no luck

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
                        <RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value=@thursdayDate.StartDate @onchange="@(() => thursdayDate.PreviewDate = thursdayDate.StartDate.Value.AddDays(-2))" DateFormat="d" />
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a 3rd party component: `RadzenDatePicker`, not a native element.
From its [documentation](https://www.radzen.com/documentation/blazor/datepicker/#a-ideventsdatepicker-eventsa), it doesn't expose an ***onchange*** callback, but ***Change*** callback.
So just replace ***onchange*** with ***Change***.